# Before and After in mySql

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible in MySql to do before and after in the same statement, my data is getting too large and i want to show only the data that has a date of 3 months before and 3 months after "FollowUp". It is date-time col. This is my statement..

```
select * from valuations 
            where Consultant = '$user'
            and FollowedUp = 0 Order by FollowUp desc";
```

Comment: Have you tried any of the date/time functions? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: you can do it by trying datetime differences

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this code

```
select * from valuations 
        where Consultant = '$user'
        AND FollowUp  >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
        AND FollowUp  <= NOW() + INTERVAL 3 MONTH
        and FollowedUp = 0 Order by FollowUp desc";
```